# Building 'Find' function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been learning Python (as my first language) from *"How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python"*. This open book teaches mostly through examples and I prefer to read the goal and build the program on my own, rather than actually reading the program code provided in the book.

However, I am struggling with creating a function which will search for a specific character in a given string and return how many times that character was counted.

The code I wrote is:

```
def find(s, x): #find s in x
    s = raw_input("Enter what you wish to find: ")
    x = raw_input("Where to search? ")
    count = 0
    for l in x: #loop through every letter in x
        if l == s: 
            count += 1
        else:
            print count
```

However, when I run this code, I get the error "**name 's' is not defined**".

The code in the book has a slightly different goal: it searches for a specific character in a string, but instead of counting how many times the character was found, it returns the position of the character in the string.

```
def find(strng, ch, start=0, step=1):
    index = start
    while 0 <= index < len(strng):
        if strng[index] == ch:
            return index
        index += step
    return -1
```

I don't really understand this code, actually.
However, even when I run the code, for example, to search for `'a'` in `'banana'`, I get the error `name 'banana' is not defined`.

What is wrong with my code? Could please someone explain me how the code provided in the book works?

Comment: Why do you have `s` and `x` as parameters when you're reassigning them in the function anyway?

Comment: Your function has two parameters, `s` and `x`, which you then ignore. How did you *call* the function, and what parameters did you pass in? Always give us a valid [mcve] and the *full traceback* of your Python errors.

Comment: Change your function to take no parameters, then write one line of code outside the function to call it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a book that does stuff like this `while 0 <= index < len(strng)` personally

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to leave a comment on my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: There are a couple things wrong with this code. The function takes in two parameters, `s` and `x`, then immediately throws them away by overwriting those variables with user input. In your for loop, every time you encounter a character that isn't `s` you print the count. You should try to separate different ideas in your code into different methods so that you can reuse code more easily.

Break down your code into small, simple ideas. If the purpose of find is to count the instances of a character in a string, it shouldn't also be handling user interaction. If you take out the raw_input and printing, you can simplify this function to:

```
def find(s, x): #find s in x
    count = 0
    for l in x: #loop through every letter in x
        if l == s: 
            count += 1
    return count
```

Now all it does it take in a character and a string and return the number of times the character appears in the string.

Now you can do your user interaction outside of the function

```
char = raw_input("Enter what you wish to find: ")
string = raw_input("Where to search?: )
print char + " appears " + `find(char, string)` + " times in " + string
```

2: The goal of this function is to find the first place where `ch` is found when walking through the characters `strng` from a starting position with a specified step. It takes in `ch`, `strng`, a position to start searching, and a step size. If the start is 0 and the step is 1, it will check every character. If the start is 2 it will check all but the first 2 characters, if the step is 2 it will check every other character, etc. This works by starting looking at the start index (`index = start`), then looping while the index is at least 0 and less than the length of the string. Since python is 0-indexed, the last character in the string has an index of one less than the length of the string, so this just restricts you from trying to check invalid indices. For each iteration of the loop, the code checks if the character at the current index is `ch`, in which case it returns the index (this is the first time it found the character). Every time it doesn't find the character at the current index, it increments the index by the step and tries again until it goes past the last character. When this happens it exits the loop and returns -1, a sentinel value which indicates that we didn't find the character in the string.

```
def find(strng, ch, start=0, step=1):
    index = start
    while 0 <= index < len(strng):
        if strng[index] == ch:
            return index
        index += step
    return -1
```

3: I'm guessing you passed some invalid parameters. `strng` should be a string, `ch` should be a single character, and `start` and `step` should be integers.

Comment: 1. Thank you. Your solution is quite clean. I will make sure to keep my code small and simple - that does seem like a great advice. 2. When you say it, it seems really simple. But I was really having a hard time breaking down and understanding the code... 3. Thank you! Because I wasn't understanding the code, I was passing invalid parameters... Everyone's been a beginner in the past, huh? Maybe one day I will be answering newbies' questions like mine. Thank you once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're taking in inputs s and x twice - once through the function arguments and once through raw input. Modify the function to do either one (say only from raw input - see below). Also, you only need to print out the count once, so you can place the print statement in the outermost indent level in the function.

```
def find(): #find s in x
    s = raw_input("Enter what you wish to find: ")
    x = raw_input("Where to search? ")
    count = 0
    for l in x: #loop through every letter in x
        if l == s: 
            count += 1

    print count
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Modify the function to do either one (say only from raw input - see below)." -> I'm sorry, but I didn't understand, since you kept both of them...

Comment: No problem! I asked simply because I wasn't understanding what you meant. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I took the parameters out of your function, moved the print command out of the else block and out of the for loop, and then wrote the last line to call the function.

```
def find(): #find s in x
    s = raw_input("Enter what you wish to find: ")
    x = raw_input("Where to search? ")
    count = 0
    for l in x: #loop through every letter in x
        if l == s: 
            count += 1
    print count

find()
```

Comment: Thank you! I meant to have the user fill in s and x and then have the function get those values. Now I understand what I did wrong! Thank you!